# Can not pull the Mongo image in Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, yaml

This is my deployment manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels: 
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env: 
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
```

I have tried several times to apply Kubernetes manifest with this Yaml file but it is throws the below mentioned error.

```
Failed to pull image "mongo": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded
  Warning  Failed     13s    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    13s    kubelet            Back-off pulling image "mongo"
  Warning  Failed     13s    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

If someone could hep me fix this issue it would be helpful.

Comment: are you able to pull any docker image from this machine ? This image tag exists and I Am able to pull this image. Is you machine behind some proxy? Also are you using Minikube ?

Comment: I can pull other images like Nginx but the only problem is with the mongo image. I am using minikube in ubutu.

Comment: Can you just do docker pull image name in your instance ??

Answer (score 2):

instead of "mongo" for the image use this: "registry.hub.docker.com/library/mongo"

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the manifest from your request and deployed it in my cluster

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels: 
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env: 
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          value: admin
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: admin123
```

mongo was deployed without issues. You must not have connectivity to internet. please check

[image]

Comment: Please expand your answer with an example and/or explanation

Comment: First I have pull the image then apply the deployment. This way it's worked.

Comment: pulling an image and then deploying it separately is not necessary. kubernetes does it automatically